# Why my Google Drive Usage Statistics are not getting updated?

Tags: google-drive

I am trying to create space in my Google Drive by deleting files but my usage statistics are still showing that my quota is almost used up.
I deleted all my files in Google Drive and emptied trash; I deleted all my Gmail messages that are greater than 10Mb in size and emptied Spams and Trash.
After this, I checked my storage at https://one.google.com/storage and found that only 6% of my free 15Gb is used (check image below).

[image]
However if return to google drive, I still get that more than 50% of my space is used.

[image]
What can I do? I desperately need at least 12Gb free space in my Google Drive.

Comment: It usually takes a bit of time for the statistics to catch up to reality. If you've emptied your trash, just be patient; it should catch up soon.

Comment: How long is SOON? I did this last Thursday; that's 5 days ago!

Comment: Have you tried putting 12GB into your storage, and come up against an error message?